# Setting PHP variables for 2 years back and 2 years in the future

Tags: beginner, php, datetime

The following code gets years (dates), 1 and 2 years back (for example 2017 - 2016) and 1 and 2 years into the future (for example 2019 - 2020). Now PHP is not my expertise so I would like to get some help cleaning this up.

Is there a different approach I should use when doing this?

```
//Filter jaren
$year = date("Y");
$yearBack = $year;
$yearBack--;
$yearDoubleBack = $yearBack;
$yearDoubleBack--;
$yearAhead = $year;
$yearAhead++;
$YearDoubleAhead = $yearAhead;
$YearDoubleAhead++;
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/rCRLM would be my suggestion

Comment: @naththedeveloper I need to get the years in between aswell so 2019 to 2020 and 2017 to 2016.

Comment: in which case, use https://3v4l.org/mWCjn

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only three-four line code rquired for getting required result:-

```
<?php

$date = date("Y"); //current year

$date_range = range($date-2, $date+2);//get year range

//print_r($date_range); //print year range

echo implode(',',$date_range);//comma seperated date range
```

Output:- https://3v4l.org/5Wq8R

Comment: Its still the same exact question. I need a clean way to get the years from 2 years ago and 2 years into the future. For example: 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020

Comment: @Robbert  check my edited solution code and working link.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class from PHP.

```
<?php

$current = new DateTime(date('Y'));

$current->modify("-2 year");
echo $current->format("Y");
//outputs 2016
$current->modify("+4 year");
echo $current->format("Y");
//outputs 2020
```

Comment: This is a working alternative approach, but is it "a review"? I think not so much.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply add and subtract the years:

```
<?php

$year = date("Y");
$yearDoubleBack = date("Y", strtotime($year . " - 2 year"));
$YearDoubleAhead = date("Y", strtotime($year . " + 2 year"));

echo '$yearDoubleBack => ' . $yearDoubleBack;
echo PHP_EOL;
echo '$YearDoubleAhead => ' . $YearDoubleAhead;
echo PHP_EOL;

$years = range($yearDoubleBack, $YearDoubleAhead);
print_r($years);
```

Check : https://3v4l.org/DLmql